# Is there any kind of development template for this site?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I don't know how this question sounds but then i gotta ask. I see a lot of sites with similar kind of background as shown in the picture below.

I wanna ask if there is some sort of template of development environment that people use to make these kind of stuff ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBevt.jpg]

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

Comment: you can try Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Bootstrap is great, but it will only get you so far. You can make something approximate to the screenshot, but not exactly. Ultimately, you need to learn how to do this on your own, without the aid of some library, if you want to actually do front-end development. Things like Bootstrap can be crutch, and just because you can slap a stylesheet on a page, doesn't mean you're a developer.